# Android endless listview not updating after fetching new contents with dedicated thread

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have a problem using [cwac-endless](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)
Please note I'm using support library and action bar sherlock (my problem could be not related to this at all). 
My custom adapter works fine (extends BaseAdapter) in a SherlockListFragment.

When I scroll down and eventually fetch new contents (with own class extending Thread), everything seems to be working fine (task comes back in onItemsReady() of DemoAdapter (extends EndlessAdapter)  , new contents are there (not displayed but objects are not empty, and added to my  object).

So when I call onDataReady(), nothing happens. Have been struggling with that issue for hours.

Do you see anything wrong in my code? No errors, the new content just doesn't shows up.

The fragment class

```
public class BusinessListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
private DemoAdapter adapter;
static public List<Business> items;

public static final String TAG = BusinessListFragment.class.getName();

public interface IItemsReadyListener {
    public void onItemsReady(List<Business> data);
}

public BusinessListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_list, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    super.onViewCreated(arg0, arg1);
    RestoApplication app = (RestoApplication) (getActivity().getApplication());
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new DemoAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), app, items);
        adapter.setRunInBackground(false);
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

static public void start() {
}
}
```

Adapter for endless functionality

```
public class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter implements IItemsReadyListener {

private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
private final Context ctx;
private final RestoApplication app;
private List<Business> items;
private static final String LOG_TAG = DemoAdapter.class.getName();
private boolean hasMoreData = false;

private int page = 1;

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

void setDataFromAnyThread(final List<Business> newData) {
    // Enqueue work on mHandler to change the data on
    // the main thread.
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.addAll(newData);
            onDataReady();
            hasMoreData = items.isEmpty();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ok done, items size: " + items.size());
        }
    });
}

public DemoAdapter(Context ctx, RestoApplication app, List<Business> items) {
    super(new SearchBusinessAdapter(ctx, app, items));
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.app = app;
    this.items = new LinkedList<Business>(items);
    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(600);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    page++; // the moment cacheInBackground will be called for the first
            // time we'll need to download page 2;
}

@Override
protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.list_item_business, null);

    View child = row.findViewById(R.id.info_container);
    child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    child = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
    child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    child.startAnimation(rotate);

    return (row);
}

@Override
protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "cacheInBackground");

    String path = new SearchBuinessUrlBuilder().businessType("1").lang(AbstractActivity.FRENCH).pageNumber(page).location("londres").build();
    new SearchBusinessLoader(mHandler, DemoAdapter.this, ctx, path).start();

    return hasMoreData;
}

@Override
protected void appendCachedData() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "appendCachedData");
}

@Override
public void onItemsReady(final List<Business> data) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onItemsReady in DemoAdapter new data.size()= "+data.size());

    setDataFromAnyThread(data);

    page++;
}

}
```

Custom adapter

```
public class SearchBusinessAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final static String BUS_TAG = SearchBusinessAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private final static String LOG_TAG = SearchBusinessAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private final Context ctx;
 private final RestoApplication app;
private final List<Business> items;


public SearchBusinessAdapter(Context ctx, RestoApplication app, List<Business> items) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.items = new LinkedList<Business>(items);
    this.app = app;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.list_item_business, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    Business item = items.get(position);

    ImageView imgThumbmail = ((ImageView)   view.findViewById(R.id.newsListItemThumbnail));
    imgThumbmail.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    TextView nameTf = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name));
    FontsWrapper.setBoldTf(ctx, new TextView[] { nameTf });
    nameTf.setText(item.getName());

    TextView adressTf = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adress));
    FontsWrapper.setCondensedTf(ctx, new TextView[] { adressTf });

    StringBuilder adressSb = new StringBuilder();
    adressSb.append(item.getStreet());
    adressSb.append("\n");
    adressSb.append(item.getZip() + " " + item.getCity());
    adressTf.setText(adressSb.toString());

    TextView cuisineTypeTf = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cuisineType));
    FontsWrapper.setLightTf(ctx, new TextView[] { cuisineTypeTf });

    StringBuilder cuisinesSb = new StringBuilder();
    cuisinesSb.append(ctx.getText(R.string.cuisine_type_label));
    cuisinesSb.append(": ");
    if (item.getCuisinesList() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.getCuisinesList().size(); i++) {
            cuisinesSb.append(item.getCuisinesList().get(i).getCuisine());
            if (i < item.getCuisinesList().size() - 1) {
                cuisinesSb.append(", ");
            }

        }

    } else {
        cuisinesSb.append("/");

    }
    cuisineTypeTf.setText(cuisinesSb);

    return view;
}

}
```

SearchBusinessLoader:

```
public class SearchBusinessLoader extends AbstractSearchBusinessLoader {
static final String LOG_TAG = SearchBusinessLoader.class.getSimpleName();

public SearchBusinessLoader(Handler handler, SearchBusinessListener listener, Context ctx, String path) {
    super();
    super.ctx = ctx;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.path = path;
}

public SearchBusinessLoader(Handler handler, IItemsReadyListener listener, Context ctx, String path) {
    super();
    super.ctx = ctx;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.endlessListener = listener;
    this.path = path;
}

@Override
InputStream getStream() throws IOException, Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "path= "+path);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(path);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    return response.getEntity().getContent();
}
}
```

Abstract class (parsing and calling the listener when done)

```
public abstract class AbstractSearchBusinessLoader extends Thread {
protected Handler handler;
protected SearchBusinessListener listener;
protected IItemsReadyListener endlessListener;
protected Context ctx;
protected String path;
private List<Business> businessesList = new ArrayList<Business>();

public interface SearchBusinessListener {
    public void onSearchResult(List<Business> bizList);
}

protected final static String LOG_TAG = AbstractSearchBusinessLoader.class.getSimpleName();

public final static int MSG_ERROR = 201;
public final static int MSG_FINISHED = 200;
public final static String BUNDLE_KEY_ERROR = "bundleKeyError";

abstract InputStream getStream() throws IOException, Exception;

@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = getStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException while getting: " + path, e);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR);
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while getting: " + path, e);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(stream, null);

        parser.next();
        while (!(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && XmlTags.SEARCHRESPONSE.equals(XmlTags.fromString(parser.getName())))) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && XmlTags.TOTALRESULTS.equals(XmlTags.fromString(parser.getName()))) {
                String totalRes = parser.nextText();
            }
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && XmlTags.SEARCHSEED.equals(XmlTags.fromString(parser.getName()))) {
                String searchSeed = parser.nextText();
            }

            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && XmlTags.BUSINESSES.equals(XmlTags.fromString(parser.getName()))) {
                parseBusinesses(parser);
            }
            parser.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "XmlPullParserException while processing business result xml", e);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException while processing business result xml", e);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onSearchResult(businessesList);
    }
    if (endlessListener != null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "endlessListener : onItemsReady");
        endlessListener.onItemsReady(businessesList);
    }
}

private void parseBusinesses(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ...


}

private List<Cuisine> parseCuisines(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ...

}

private List<Picture> parsePictures(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ....
}

private void parseBusiness(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ...
```

}

Comment: Get rid of your `Runnable` from `setDataFromAnyThread()`, as `onItemsReady()` is called on the main application thread, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CommonsWare but I have android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
If I do that. (onItemsReady() is called on the listener from the class I wrote, extending Thread)

Comment: Then you are doing something very strange. If you look at the `demo/` project in the repo, you will see that it does not need to use `post()`.

Comment: But if I use my own custom class in its own Thread to fetch new datas, isn't it normal that I shouldn't be able to touch UI thread? I'll post the code here below so you can see how I do. If you could be so nice to have a look, maybe your help will not just fix my bug, but improve my coding skills. (I have installed the demo project and looked deeply into it, and also have inspired my self from http://droidista.blogspot.be/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html

Comment: (updated my question so you can see how I fetch the datas). Do you see anything wrong with it?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Never mind -- I was forgetting how `setRunInBackground(false)` worked (not my code, but rather a contribution from another developer). That being said, your code is very confusing, and I have no idea how to help you further, other than to suggest perhaps following the `EndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment` class from the `demo/` project a bit more closely and use an `AsyncTask` rather than a `Thread` and `post()`. Also, I would not recommend naming something `...Loader` if it is not actually implementing part of the `Loader` framework in Android.

Comment: the solution was very simple. I had to notify my adapter whit the new  data set: 
SearchBusinessAdapter adapter = (SearchBusinessAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
items.addAll(newData);
adapter.setItems(items);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Very related to my own implementation (wich is based on http://droidista.blogspot.be/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html)
Thanks for the help anyway